# Why does this span tag only changes for less than a second?

Tags: javascript, html

This is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>date of birth</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <div id="div1">
            <h1>Age in days</h1>
        </div>
        <form id="user_input">
            <input id="age_years" type="number" placeholder="Put your age in years">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="submit_button" onclick="ageInDays()">   
        </form>  
        <div>
            <p id="finalText">This is your age in days: <span id="span">0</span>  </p>
        </div>
    </main> 
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my Javascript:

```
"use strict"

function ageInDays() {
    let ageInYears = document.getElementById("age_years").value;
    let ageDays = ageInYears * 365;
    // para.appendChild(text);
    document.getElementById("span").textContent= ageDays;
}
```

When I run the code, it only shows the answer for a split second and then it goes away. Does anybody know why this happens?

Comment: As per my guess, the code in javascript is executed first, and then DOM HTML content is rendered so span gets empty when page is finished loading. Try running javascript after the HTML has been completely rendered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page reloads after showing the value in span because it is the default behavior while submitting forms, if you simply want to calculate the age in days and show it into span tag and don't want the values to be submitted using form then you can simply do this, just add `onsubmit="return false"` to your form element,
Like this

```
<form id="user_input" onsubmit="return false">
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Glad it helped !
Can you mark the suitable answer correct, so that this question is closed.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It actually submits the form by defaults, hence it refreshes the page, try to prevent the action:

in your HTML:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="submit_button" onclick="ageInDays(event)">
```

in your JS:

```
function ageInDays(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevents from reloading the page
    let ageInYears = document.getElementById("age_years").value;
    let ageDays = ageInYears * 365;
    // para.appendChild(text);
    document.getElementById("span").textContent= ageDays;
}
```

Comment: This one works too, I get now why It wasn't working, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible that javascript is running before HTML is rendered. Try this one is .js file.

```
window.onload = function(){
"use strict"

function ageInDays() {
    let ageInYears = document.getElementById("age_years").value;
    let ageDays = ageInYears * 365;
    // para.appendChild(text);
    document.getElementById("span").textContent= ageDays;
}
});
```